# Replace folder if same name

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a folder where I will save the files. If a folder with a specific name already exists I want to replace this folder with a new, empty one. 
Dont know what to do with this Else thing. Im getting run time error 75 path/file access error.

```
Path = "\\ASD\"
d = Format(Date, "yyyymmdd")
f = "NBT Reports "
If Len(Dir(Path & d, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
MkDir (Path & f & d)
ElseIf ???
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with something like this:

```
        Sub test()
        Dim strPath As String
            strPath = "\\ASD\"
        Dim d As String
            d = Format(Date, "yyyymmdd")
        Dim f As String
            f = "\NBT Reports"
        Dim Folder As String
            Folder = Dir(strPath & d, vbDirectory)


            If Folder = vbNullString Then
                Debug.Print "Doesnt Exist"

                MkDir strPath
                MkDir strPath & d
                MkDir strPath & d & f
            Else
                Debug.Print "Exists"

                Dim oFSO As Object
                   Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

                oFSO.deletefolder Left(strPath, Len(strPath) - 1)

                    If Dir(Left(strPath, Len(strPath) - 1)) = "" Then
                        MkDir strPath
                        MkDir strPath & d
                        MkDir strPath & d & f
                    End If
            End If
        End Sub
```

The second nested IF statement is present because the oFSO seems to hang when deleting files, so if you question the directory again it seems to free it and then allows you to create the directory again.